# Rails auto update database attribute after clicking submit on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I am using simple_form in rails to create certain events. To create a new event, you are required to login as a user. The form will ask the user to enter the event name, start date, and end date. When the user clicks the submit button, I want the form to automatically update the attribute user_id in the database.

Right now in the database, the user_id field in the events table is always set to null. However I need this attribute to be set to:

`events.user_id = current_user.id`

Here is my events table for more info: [image]

Note: I manually entered the values for user_id in this database.

**Question:** How do I update a database attribute, after a user clicks submit? Or is there a default way of always setting the user_id when a new event is created?

Here is the code in the new.html.erb events view

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :start_at %>
    <%= f.input :end_at %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your create method in your event controller, add your

```
events.user_id = current_user.id
```

before the save.

e.g. if you create the event (in the `def create` method) with `@event = Event.new(params[:event])`
then do `@link.user_id = current_user.id on the next line`
You can probably do `@link.user = current_user` and rails will figure the id out.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I added `@event.user_id = current_user.id` in the (`def create method`)